# Can I set a maximum and minimum payment amount on Paypal

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway

I am new to making a payment gate way and require restricting purchases between a predefined minimum and maximum.  I searched Google, finding [this](https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/How-to-use-PayPal/Can-I-set-a-minimum-payment-amount/td-p/6010) as the most useful result.  Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the maximum with `MAXAMT` - [read more](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_SetExpressCheckout)

However there is no option to set the minimum with Paypal. But you can write a simple JS that checks on submit the form field value and throws an error if the amount is less than expected:

```
function checkMinimum() {
    var min = 5;
    if( parseFloat( document.formName.fieldName.value ) < min ) {
        alert("Minimum amount should be not less than $" + min + ". Spend more.");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```