# Insert code for PayPal minimum order dollar amount

Tags: paypal, minimum

While searching for days for answers to how to set a minimum order subtotal in WordPress with PayPal, I found this thread: [Can I set a maximum and minimum payment amount on Paypal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782658/paypal-html-variable-can-i-set-a-maximum-and-minimum-payment-amount)

But now that I found an answer, I don't know how to implement it!  Can anyone tell me where to put the code suggested?:

```
function checkMinimum() {
   var min = 5;
   if( parseFloat( document.formName.fieldName.value ) < min ) {
        alert("Minimum amount should be not less than $" + min + ". Spend more.");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a form or page before your site redirects to the paypal site you can place the code on that page